# After STSADM restore to new farm getting DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, navigation, sharepoint-2007, moss

I did a restoration of the complete site collection using the stsadm restore into a new farm. The site as it is work good but I have one wiered issue that whenever I visit the root site I get the following error.

[image: MOSS 2007 Site Error]

If I visit the sub sites directly this is what I see in the top navigation

[image: Error in navigation when you hover on it]

Here is what I have found in troubleshooting it

- If I do a app pool recycle or IISReset the issue is gone and site works perfect
- The error comes back after few minutes of site usage

The different steps that I took after looking at few other places are

- Deactivate and reactivate the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure
- Change the master page
- Reset the blob cache, output cache and object cache (I doubt this was the fix, cause cache is not enabled)
- Clear the sharepoint configuration cache as per this [site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache-for-timer-job-and-psconfig-errors.aspx)

Please let me know your thoughts on how I can fix this and following in the farm details
Server - Windows 2003 x86
SharePoint - MOSS 2007 with build number 12.0.0.6656

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating and reactivating the publishing site feature in the Site Collection and Web fixed it.